# Finding optimal translation & rotation to place a 3d model into its visual hull

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, 3d

The title already sums up my question pretty well:

- I've got a pretty accurate 3d model of some object. This object is usually non-convex and it also may have some holes etc.
- This object is placed (translation & rotation) into some position and pictures are taken from specific positions and angles. Since I got extrinsic information for these cameras, I should be able to construct a pretty accurate, but coarse visual hull of this object in this fixed, unknown position.

Now I'm interested in the actual position of this object, i.e. the geometric transformation (translation & rotation) to place the 3d model into the visual hull.

As soon as I've constructed a visual hull, I think I would try the ICP algorithm ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point ), but I'm rather pessimistic that this algorithm solves the problem accurately enough (since the visual hull is so coarse). Maybe you can suggest me some more promising methods/paper/books to approach this kind of problem.